# I want to send data from javascript to an MVC controller and switch window to IActionResult of that controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a javascript function which should filter data about products using checkboxes.
I have a loop which makes an array from checked checkboxes.
This data is sent to an MVC controller.
Controller's code is executed even cshtml file and everything works fine, only thing I don't know how to do is to make the website switch to the controller's URL after post method is executed. I want to make it work like I called MVC controller normally.

```
   var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("check");

        var categories = [];

        const START_INDEX = 0;
        for (let elementIndex = START_INDEX;
            elementIndex < checkboxes.length;
            elementIndex++)
        {
            if (checkboxes[elementIndex].checked)
            {
                categories.push(checkboxes[elementIndex].value);

            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {Kategorije:categories},
            url: '../Home/filter-products',
            success: function (result)
            {
                window.location = result.url;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view you can use as below

```
@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));
```

You can use this in the JavaScript file as:

```
var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
location.href = url;
```